# mongoose and lazy initialize attributes not executing in correct scope

Tags: attributes, mongoose, lazy-evaluation

I'm using mongoose for my data access layer, and I really like the different
features it offers to create document models (Attributes, Methods, Static Methods..)

I use the virtual attribute feature of mongoose to create attributes that will not be persisted to MongoDB. However, these attributes are **computationaly expensive** (and using them  many times is not helping me).
 Lets take for example the same example on [mongoose virtual](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/virtuals.html)
it persists `person.name.first` and `person.name.last`,  and uses virtual attribute for  `person.name.full`

Let's say I want to compute person.name.full only one time per the lifetime of the document
(and if I allow to set the attribute or its dependent fields like in the example, then also for every get after a dirty set).

I need an extra variable in the document scope, so naturally I used closures for this
but the **'this'** scope in the function that computes the attribute, is of the **global** object, and not of the document I'm working on.

Code:

```
var makeLazyAttribute = function(computeAttribute) {
    var attribute = null;
    return function() {
        if(!attribute) {
            attribute = computeAttribute();     
        }
        return attribute;
    }
};

MySchema.virtual('myAttribute').get(makeLazyAttribute(function () {
    // some code that uses this, this should be the document I'm working on
    // error: first is not defined, inspecting what is this gives me the global object
        return this.first + this.last

}));
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, ok, I've made some progress `makeLazyAttribute` does execute in the document scope
so I only needed to change `attribute = computeAttribute();` to
 `attribute = computeAttribute.call(this);` .

However, now Im only remembering the first ever `computeAttribute()` invocation instead of remembering 
the first function invocation per each document.
Must have a way to mitigate this.